# How does the WP Super Cache plugin hijack the main post loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I'm curious about how the [WP Super Cache plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) works. It is a plugin that caches certain pages on Wordpress so that the server doesn't have build the page every time it is requested.

I've read around a little about how server-side caching in Wordpress works, and I found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/19crcn/best_practice_for_hijacking_main_loop_and_caching/), which says that you can add a filter to 'posts_request' hijack and stop the main query (which kickstarts the whole page building in Wordpress), and another filter to 'posts_results' to insert your own cached page. Between these two filters, you can stop Wordpress from building a page from scratch.

I've been pouring through the WP Super Cache scripts though, and I don't find any filters for these two actions anywhere! Does anyone have any idea of how WP Super Cache hijacks the main post loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "hijack the main post loop"? What is it exactly you are trying to achieve? If it is "general understanding" you might have to look through the source code, chances are it describes how it interacts with the framework.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the plugin's authors (Automattic and https://profiles.wordpress.org/donncha) and asking them?

Comment: I never knew I could do that. I can try it. Thanks!